# Floating action button full screen transition

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Floating action transition ,my purpose is after click on float action button transition of full screen transition must happen,it seems like gmail effect,when we click on compose email button a full screen is acquire by compose mail screen.

Comment: i think you got answer from here https://github.com/lightSky/Awesome-MaterialDesign

Comment: can i achieve this by using reveal circle ....

Comment: actually what i tried today is onclick event of floating action button i am calling second activity using intent method.....am i doing right thing????

Comment: RevealCircle will do it with the same revealing animation whereas using an onClick on a floating button won't look like Reveal Circle's animation. And No, setting onClick is not the wrong way. It's fine actually.